# Installing PAPI on MacOS

Tags: macos, installation, papi

I am trying to install `PAPI` on my Mac (10.14.6)

In case there are no information about macos in `INSTALL.txt`
Tried the standard installation:

`git clone https://bitbucket.org/icl/papi.git`

`cd papi/src`

`./configure --prefix=$PWD/install` (or just only `./configure`)

But after executing the `./configure` command, the following error pops:

```
checking for timer_create and timer_*ettime symbols in base system... not found checking for timer_create and timer_*ettime symbols in
-lrt... not found checking for timer_create and timer_*ettime symbols in -lrt -lpthread... configure: error: cannot find timer_create and timer_*ettime symbols neither in the base system libraries nor in
-lrt, nor in -lrt -lpthread
```

Does someone know what software i need to install to get that timer?

Or maybe there is another way to install papi on macos?

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that the official PAPI mailing list is ptools-perfapi@icl.utk.edu. You might have better luck sending an email directly there.

As far as I can tell MacOS lacks the functionality for allowing PAPI to access CPU performance counters. Moreover, although in theory it should be possible to build PAPI without the CPU component, by default PAPI always configures the perf_event and perf_event_uncore components, which only work for Linux as they rely on the perf_event system call to work.