# What is the closest syscall to `perf_event_open` on MacOS

Tags: macos, profiling, system-calls, perf

What syscalls should I use on MacOS (both Arm and Intel) to obtain CPU event counters?

Perfect for me would be something close to Linux's `perf_event_open` syscall.

For example: How would I count L2-cache-misses and branch-misses of some random function f() inside huge application via syscall?

Comment: An answer on [Installing PAPI on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69531604) says they think MacOS doesn't have a standard API for this which the PAPI library could use.  IDK if that's changed in the last 1.5 years, or if they were mistaken.